# ARM NEON Intrinsics. What does vmulq_lane_f32 do?

Tags: floating-point, arm, neon, intrinsics

On googling the best I could find was

```
float32x4_t vmulq_lane_f32 (float32x4_t, float32x2_t, const int)
Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.f32 q0, q0, d0[0]
```

which looking into neon programmers' guide suggests that it is vector to scalar multiplication. But there are other APIs for exactly that purpose.

```
float32x4_t vmulq_n_f32 (float32x4_t, float32_t)
Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.f32 q0, q0, d0[0]
```

So what I still don't know is what is the purpose of first API and what is the concept of lane in it. 
EDIT : Source of above info : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

Comment: Broadcasts an element of the second vector argument specified by the index argument and multiplies it by first vector argument.

Comment: A scalar `float` and one element of a `float32xN_t` may be conceptually the same thing, but they're very different as far as a C compiler is concerned. Why _not_ support both?

Answer (score 0):

```
float32x4_t vmulq_lane_f32 (float32x4_t, float32x2_t, const int)
Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.f32 q0, q0, d0[0]
```

it should have been written as

```
float32x4_t dst = vmulq_lane_f32 (float32x4_t q, float32x2_t d, const int c)
Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.f32 dst, q, d[c]
```

where `c` can be 0-1.

In the second example

```
float32x4_t vmulq_n_f32 (float32x4_t, float32_t)
Form of expected instruction(s): vmul.f32 q0, q0, d0[0]
```

`float32_t` is a non vectorial type meaning compiler will produce necessary code to load that argument into a vector register then use it, so you get that for free.

With `vmulq_lane_f32` you tell explicitly which register to use and you have to  make sure that it contains what you want prior to that.

```
$ cat vmulq.c 
#include "arm_neon.h"

register float32x4_t a asm("q4");
register float32x2_t b asm("d10");
register float32x4_t c asm("q6");
register float32x4_t d asm("q7");

void foo() {
    c = vmulq_lane_f32(a, b, 1);
    d = vmulq_lane_f32(a, b, 0);
}

void bar() {
    a = vmulq_n_f32(a, 5);
}

$objdump -d vmulq.o

vmulq.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <foo>:
   0:   f3a8c96a    vmul.f32    q6, q4, d10[1]
   4:   f3a8e94a    vmul.f32    q7, q4, d10[0]
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <bar>:
   c:   ed9f7b01    vldr    d7, [pc, #4]    ; 18 <bar+0xc>
  10:   f3a88947    vmul.f32    q4, q4, d7[0]
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  18:   40a00000    .word   0x40a00000
  1c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`float32_t` is NOT a neon datatype; so `float32_t` values have to be transferred between the neon coprocessor and the main processor. The entire neon execution pipelines stalls whenever such a transfer occurs, so the cost of such a transfer is significant.

`vmulq_n_f32` will stall the neon execution pipeline in order to transfer the `float32_t` value; `vmulq_lane_f32` will not.

Potentially (in a magical rainbow world where pipeline stalls never happen), you can run up to 5.5x faster if you use `mmulq_lane_f32` instead of `fmulq_n_f32`. And in ordinary real-world cases you can run 2 or 3x faster if you judiciously use aligned `vldq_f32/vstq_f32` to keep `vmulq_lane_f32` fed and pipelining properly.